# Retrieving date value from google doc gives me strange values

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I am trying to read a column value which has date in mm/dd/yyyy format, but I am getting strange values when i use the below script.

```
var data = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for(i in data){
  Logger.log(data[i][4]);
}
```

The column value in the doc is 1/24/2015 but i get 42028.0 from the above script.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific format for a date.

### Code

```
 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM-yyyy-dd");
 Logger.log(formattedDate);
```

### Logger

[15-02-24 16:52:51:958 CET] 02-2015-24

---

API for more informations:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities

Comment: This gives me 01-1970-01 not the date that I pass.Is there something that I should do differently

Comment: new Date( data[i][4] ) give 01-1970-01 ?

Comment: Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date( data[i][3] ), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd")); gives me 1970-01-01. whatever the value present in data[i][3] the result doen't change it is the same 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the number of days passed since Jan. 1st 1900, Javascript way of keep track, just convert it back to a date with `var currDate = new Date( data[i][4] )`.